# How can I get my extension enabled after a takedown?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

My extension - Buttercup - was taken down without notice over the weekend. The item ID is **heflipieckodmcppbnembejjmabajjjj**. Is there a common procedure to getting extensions back online after a take down? Or some way to debug what the reason was to remove it from the store?

This is of great concern to us, and I'm sure many developers would like to know how to best remedy this in the future. What can we do to prevent such a situation in the future?

We added a privacy policy after the take down - could this have been the reason?

The code for the extension [is here](https://github.com/buttercup/buttercup-browser-extension).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet may be to refactor and update your code to make sure that you're using the current best practices. Chrome deprecates parts of its API all the time, so make sure that you aren't using anything deprecated. Make sure you're using the latest options UI (rather than page) and (if possible) use event pages/scripts over persistent background workers.

Check the permissions in the manifest are only what you need, and that it's valid and up to date. Increment the version number.

Once your spring clean is done update the web store with the new version. Hopefully it will be enough to trigger a re-evaluation of the code, or possibly fix whatever Google took exception to.

Comment: I'm currently undertaking some spring cleaning in hope that it works. One area of concern I have, if it is indeed due to some code I'm using, is where we save the last set of data from a login form the user has submitted (our extension is a password manager). We write it temporarily to localstorage in the background. What sort of things normally get an extension pulled - would security stuff like this cause problems?

Comment: After a bit of refactoring, cleaning and reduction of permissions, my extension was put back up. I had to upload a **new version** of the extension for them to re-review it.

Comment: @PerryMitchell writing to any type of storage shouldn't be an issue so long as it's in the permissions. Also yeah, you need to upload it as a new version with a higher version number for them to reëvaluate it. I suggest using [semver](http://semver.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You can file a report about this at
https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/contact/developer_support/?hl=en so the support team may help you know the reason why it was taken down. Possible reason of this is it's a dead link. See this related [thread](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-apps/XPbAM8nvbik). Also may sure that you didn't violate any [Terms & Conditions](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/terms).

Comment: I've filed 2 requests through that form with no response. I had only added the privacy policy *after* the take down occurred.